# SQL: Not removing but replacing zip code data with Other

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a bunch of bad zip codes in my data that I am looking replace with Other. How do I do that in SQL then there are over 100 zip codes? The only thing I was thinking of doing was a CASE when statement.
But say I want to replace a zipcode: 12233 with Other. How would I do that?

YouTube and Google.  Case when statements

Comment: Case is an **expression** not a **statement**. Please us a [MRE] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Create a mapping table - and use that to replace the bad entries.  One way to do that without having to actually create a table or update the actual table:

```
Declare @invalidZipCodes Table (ZipCode char(5));
 Insert Into @invalidZipCodes (ZipCode)
 Values ('12233'), ('11223');
```

Then you can use that in your regular query:

```
Select ZipCode = iif(izc.ZipCode Is Not Null, 'Other', zc.ZipCode)
  From ZipCodes zc
  Left Join @invalidZipCodes izc On izc.ZipCode = zc.ZipCode
```